# Sort from publication doesn't carry through to client

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm using `meteor 1.3.2` and trying to search through a mongo db collection via text query.

**Server Code** - I publish a collection called `docsearch` which returns a find of another collection called `Docs`

```
Meteor.publish('docsearch', query => {
  if (query) {
    return Docs.find(
      { $text: {
          $search: query
        }
      },
      {
        fields: {
          score: {
            $meta: 'textScore'
          }
        },
        sort: {
          score: {
            $meta: 'textScore'
          }
        }
      }
    );
  }
});
```

**Client Code** - I have a helper function that takes in a query parameter

```
dataQueryFunc: () => query => {
  if (query !== '' && query.length > 1) {
    Meteor.subscribe('docsearch', query);
    return Docs.find({}, { sort: [["score", "desc"]] }).fetch();
  }
}
```

No matter what I pass in as the query, I just get the regular order of `Docs`. I'm following tutorials written by OkGrow and JustMeteor which both say this is how it's done.

What am I missing. Would subscribing to `docs` elsewhere in the app be corrupting the `Docs.find()` call?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is: Subscription is not in reactive context. That means when client subscribes to particular collection for the first time, server publish the collections based on the query and closes the connection with client.

To make subscription reactive, you have to put Meteor.subscribe() under reactive context i.e:

```
Tracker.autorun(function(){
   Meteor.subscribe('docsearch', query));
});
```

Above code still wont work, because Tracker.autorun() triggers when there is a change in reactive context inside function(). So, go and make 'query' as Session variable:
Session variable itself is reactive

```
Session.set('query',/*query goes here*/});

Tracker.autorun(function(){
   Meteor.subscribe('docsearch', Session.get('query'));
});
```

So now, whenever there is a change encountered in Session variable 'query'(in any part of your code), subscription changes due to reactive context.

you can change Session variable using set command.

```
Session.set(<session variable>,<variable value>);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your client-side sort seems incorrect.

```
return Docs.find({}, { sort: [["score", "desc"]] }).fetch();
```

Should be:

```
return Docs.find({}, { sort: {score: -1} }).fetch();
```

Also you say that your data query function is called from a *helper*. That should not be the case. Depending on how you're performing the search that function either needs to be in an event handler or in your template's `.onCreated()` handler.

Comment: I said I have a `helper function` - that function is not called until an event is fired. In this case, the event is fired in a react component. After messing around with this more, it seems that my code actually was working all along, it's just that mongo's search results are frankly terrible. For example `grid` does not show the `grid` article, but `gridd` does. I'll just have to work around that.